# socket.io doesn't seem to work in production environment (w Docker and Caddy)

Tags: angular, express, docker, caddy

I am using socket.io in express.js and socket.io-client in angular 4 with the following Caddyfile (a part of it):

```
proxy /api web-api:8080 {
    transparent
}

proxy /socket.io web-api:8080 {
  header_upstream Host {host}
  header_upstream X-Real-IP {remote}
  header_upstream X-Forwarded-For {remote}
  websocket
}
```

The Caddy server is executed through a Dockerfile with the following command:

```
CMD         ["caddy", "-http2=false"]
```

On the angular part I am using the following code (part of it):

```
let observable = new Observable(observer => {
  this.socket = io.connect(`${environment.apiUrl}`);
  this.socket.on('message', (message: any) => {
    observer.next(message);
  });
  return () => {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  };
});
return observable;
```

and on the express.js the following:

```
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

In development mode (neither docker or caddy is being used) everything works as expected, but in production mode I keep getting POST and GET responses/requests (without any error) in browser's console in this form:

```
...
http://my-app-example/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MFB2-Bv
http://my-app-example/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MFB31eM
http://my-app-example/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MFB2_oS
...
```

It seems that the 'emit' event never get fired. Maybe it has to do with sockets communication inside Docker container.